# Flutter size container to content within it

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, containers, expand

I am trying to create box within my widget that will size dynamically based on the content published within it, but it appears to be getting truncated when it hits the overflow.

[image]

```
Padding _buildReviewsSnapshot(Tasker user) {
    return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
                // flex: 3,
                child: GridView.count(
              crossAxisCount: 2,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              children: List.generate(6, (index) {
                return Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(
                            color: const Color.fromRGBO(212, 221, 230, 1)),
                        borderRadius:
                            const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(6),
                    clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      child: Column(children: [
                        Row(children: const [
                          Icon(
                            Icons.star_rate,
                            size: 16,
                            color: Colors.amber,
                          ),
                          Icon(
                            Icons.star_rate,
                            size: 16,
                            color: Colors.amber,
                          ),
                          Icon(
                            Icons.star_rate,
                            size: 16,
                            color: Colors.amber,
                          ),
                          Icon(
                            Icons.star_rate,
                            size: 16,
                            color: Colors.amber,
                          ),
                          Icon(
                            Icons.star_border,
                            size: 16,
                            color: Colors.grey,
                          ),
                        ]),
                        const SizedBox(height: 10),
                        Text(
                            "Charlee wasn’t present at the job but we had extremely clear instructions on what to do and how to do it. Would highly recommend as the attention to detail was spot on",
                            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1),
                        Text("- Charlee R",
                            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2),
                      ]),
                    ));
              }),
            )),
          ],
        ));
  }
```

Comment: Try wrapping `Text` with `Flexible`

Comment: That makes the overflow, what I am after is for the container with the border to grow or shrink to the size of the content

Comment: can you add a screenshot of which type of error or your actual result?

Comment: @BossNass you can use IntrinsicHeight,  please refer this, https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicHeight-class.html

Comment: Do all containers have the same size or dynamic?

Comment: Dynamic, so they scale to the content. this is just a place holder of super long content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all container size the same then use this code. If not check Second Answer:-

### Answer 1:-

[image]

```
Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                  // flex: 3,
                  child: GridView.count(
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                children: List.generate(6, (index) {
                  return Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(
                              color: const Color.fromRGBO(212, 221, 230, 1)),
                          borderRadius:
                              const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(6),
                      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                        child: Column(children: [
                          Row(children: const [
                            Icon(
                              Icons.star_rate,
                              size: 16,
                              color: Colors.amber,
                            ),
                            Icon(
                              Icons.star_rate,
                              size: 16,
                              color: Colors.amber,
                            ),
                            Icon(
                              Icons.star_rate,
                              size: 16,
                              color: Colors.amber,
                            ),
                            Icon(
                              Icons.star_rate,
                              size: 16,
                              color: Colors.amber,
                            ),
                            Icon(
                              Icons.star_border,
                              size: 16,
                              color: Colors.grey,
                            ),
                          ]),
                          const SizedBox(height: 10),
                          Text(
                            "Charlee wasn’t present at the job but we had extremely clear instructions on what to do and how to do it. Would highly recommend as the attention to detail was spot on",
                            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1,
                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                            maxLines: 5,
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(height: 10),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 150,
                            child: Text(
                              "- Charlee R",
                              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2,
                              textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ]),
                      ));
                }),
              )),
            ],
          )),
```

### Answer 2:-

Use this package flutter_staggered_grid_view. Using this package use can create these types of containers.

[flutter_staggered_grid_view](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view)

##### Output:-

[image]

Code:-

```
import 'package:archive/UI/screens/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_staggered_grid_view/flutter_staggered_grid_view.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Demo(),
    );
  }
}

class Demo extends StatelessWidget {
  String content =
      "Charlee wasn’t present at the job but we had extremely clear instructions on what to do and how to do it. Would highly recommend as the attention to detail was spot on";
  String content1 =
      "Charlee wasn’t present at the job but we had extremely clear instructions on what to do and how to do it. Would highly recommend as the attention to detail was spot on Charlee wasn’t present at the job but we had extremely clear instructions on what to do and how to do it. Would highly recommend as the attention to detail was spot on ";
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                // flex: 3,
                child: StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
                    staggeredTileBuilder: (int index) => StaggeredTile.fit(1),
                    crossAxisCount: 2,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              border: Border.all(
                                  color:
                                      const Color.fromRGBO(212, 221, 230, 1)),
                              borderRadius:
                                  const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(6),
                          clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                            child: Column(children: [
                              Row(children: const [
                                Icon(
                                  Icons.star_rate,
                                  size: 16,
                                  color: Colors.amber,
                                ),
                                Icon(
                                  Icons.star_rate,
                                  size: 16,
                                  color: Colors.amber,
                                ),
                                Icon(
                                  Icons.star_rate,
                                  size: 16,
                                  color: Colors.amber,
                                ),
                                Icon(
                                  Icons.star_rate,
                                  size: 16,
                                  color: Colors.amber,
                                ),
                                Icon(
                                  Icons.star_border,
                                  size: 16,
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                ),
                              ]),
                              const SizedBox(height: 10),
                              Text(
                                index.isEven ? content : content1,
                                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1,
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(height: 10),
                              SizedBox(
                                width: 150,
                                child: Text(
                                  "- Charlee R",
                                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2,
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ]),
                          ));
                    }),
              ),
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

I hope this answer is useful for you.

Comment: Not all same size, but to be height of the content

Comment: Check answer 2. I hope this is useful for you and I will eligible for bounty.

Comment: since add this, this entire file crashes

Comment: 100% some bug in the above and as I am not familiar with the staggered grid view I cannot find it but the moment we comment this out it works

Comment: which types of bugs do you explain?

Comment: code was missing item count which caused the app to freeze, after adding that it worked as expected. thanks

Comment: It's my pleasure. Am I eligible for bounty?

Comment: all sorted, we have a few other flutter questions if you are keen

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240168/discussion-between-jeel-bhatti-and-boss-nass).

Answer (score 1):

Try using **ConstrainedBox**. It will adapt the parent widget size to the child widget size.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Flexible' make the container change its size depending on its content

*Edit looks like get the wrong idea about it, sorry. Try changing `Flexible` I mentioned before and change it into `Wrap` widget.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its help to you. there is two way to display the output

1. If you display full text of the your content you can used
   `SingleChildScrollView()` Wrap your `Column()` inside
   SingleChildScrollView() refer [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html)

   ```
   SingleChildScrollView(
           child: Column(
             children: [
               Row(
                 children: const [
                   Icon(
                     Icons.star_rate,
                     size: 16,
                     color: Colors.amber,
                   ),
                   Icon(
                     Icons.star_rate,
                     size: 16,
                     color: Colors.amber,
                   ),
                   Icon(
                     Icons.star_rate,
                     size: 16,
                     color: Colors.amber,
                   ),
                   Icon(
                     Icons.star_rate,
                     size: 16,
                     color: Colors.amber,
                   ),
                   Icon(
                     Icons.star_border,
                     size: 16,
                     color: Colors.grey,
                   ),
                 ],
               ),
               const SizedBox(
                 height: 10,
               ),
               Text(
                 "Charlee wasn’t present at the job but we had extremely clear instructions on what to do and how to do it. Would highly recommend as the attention to detail was spot on",
                 style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1,
               ),
               Text(
                 "- Charlee R",
                 style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2,
               ),
             ],
           ),
         ),
   ```

Your result screen using SingleChildScrollView ->

[image]

2. Add your `Text` Widget inside `Expanded` refer `Expanded` Widget [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html):

   ```
     Expanded(
           child: Text(
             "Charlee wasn’t present at the job but we had extremely clear instructions on what to do and how to do it. Would highly recommend as the attention to detail was spot on",
             style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1,
           ),
         ),
   ```

Your result screen using Expanded-> [image]

Comment: this still doesn't scale the container to the content